# ApplicationModalAdorner GetLayoutClip() InvalidOperationException

Tags: wpf, adorner

I have my own ApplicationModalAdorner. Sometimes I get an `InvalidOperationException` from `GetLayoutClip()` which I override. The call to `TransformToAncestor` causes the exception. I am unable to reproduce the exception (I see the exception in the logging quite a lot). Maybe the Window isn't completly rendered? I'm looking for a reproduction (maybe in a simple app) and a cause/solution for this exception. I get the exception a couple of times in the same minute. I prefer a solution without a Dispatcher.

Relevant callstack part:

```
Wrapped Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: An exception occured while handling another exception;
   bij System.Windows.Media.Visual.TrySimpleTransformToAncestor(Visual ancestor, Boolean inverse, GeneralTransform& generalTransform, Matrix& simpleTransform)
   bij System.Windows.Media.Visual.TransformToAncestor(Visual ancestor)
   bij x.x.x.ApplicationModalAdorner.WindowRect()
   bij x.x.x.ApplicationModalAdorner.GetLayoutClip(Size layoutSlotSize)
   bij System.Windows.UIElement.ensureClip(Size layoutSlotSize)
   bij System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   bij System.Windows.Documents.AdornerLayer.ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
   bij System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   bij System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   bij System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator.ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
   bij System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   bij System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   bij System.Windows.Controls.Control.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
   bij System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   bij System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   bij MS.Internal.Helper.ArrangeElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size arrangeSize)
   bij System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   bij System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   bij System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   bij System.Windows.Controls.Grid.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   bij System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   bij System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
```

Code

```
public class ApplicationModalAdorner : Adorner
{
    private SolidColorBrush _brush;

    private XamDialogWindow Window
    {
        get
        {
            return (XamDialogWindow)AdornedElement;
        }
    }

    private Window MainWindow
    {
        get
        {
            if (Application.Current != null)
            {
                return Application.Current.MainWindow;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public ApplicationModalAdorner(UIElement adornedElement)
        : base(adornedElement)
    {
        _brush = (SolidColorBrush)FindResource("ModalBackgroundBrush");

        Window.Moved += WindowMoved;
        Window.WindowStateChanged += WindowStateChanged;
        MainWindow.SizeChanged += MainWindowSizeChanged;
    }

    // There is no WindowClosed event. Infragistics states that when a window is closed,
    // the WindowStateChanged event gets triggerd and the value will be Hidden. Because 
    // the ApplicationModal windows cannot be hidden, this is a nice way to clean events.
    private void WindowStateChanged(object sender, WindowStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewWindowState == Infragistics.Controls.Interactions.WindowState.Hidden)
        {
            Window.Moved -= WindowMoved;
            Window.WindowStateChanged -= WindowStateChanged;
            if (MainWindow != null)
            {
                MainWindow.SizeChanged -= MainWindowSizeChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private void WindowMoved(object sender, MovedEventArgs e)
    {
        InvalidateVisual();
    }

    private void MainWindowSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        InvalidateVisual();
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(_brush, null, WindowRect());
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
    }

    protected override Geometry GetLayoutClip(Size layoutSlotSize)
    {
        var xamDialogWindowRect = new Rect(new Point(Window.Left, Window.Top), layoutSlotSize);
        var geometryGroup = new GeometryGroup();
        geometryGroup.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(WindowRect()));
        geometryGroup.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(xamDialogWindowRect));
        return geometryGroup;
    }

    private Rect WindowRect()
    {
        var transformToAncestor = Window.TransformToAncestor(MainWindow);
        var topLeft = transformToAncestor.Inverse.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        var bottomRight = transformToAncestor.Inverse.Transform(new Point(MainWindow.ActualWidth, MainWindow.ActualHeight));
        return new Rect(topLeft, bottomRight);
    }

    public override GeneralTransform GetDesiredTransform(GeneralTransform transform)
    {
        InvalidateVisual();
        return base.GetDesiredTransform(transform);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *"An exception occured while handling another exception"* I'd possibly be interested in that other exception that is mentioned there... Getting an exception when the whole thing is already in an odd state is not as interesting as the first point of failure.

Comment: @grek40 the first exception is the same exception, i get a couple of the same exceptions short after each other

Comment: Do you get the same exception the first time the code is executed (breakpoint it)?

Comment: @grek40 In the logging I see that it's always the same exception. I am unable to reproduce the exception. I tried putting breakpoints in the code.

Comment: Then you should use a try-catch all and put the breakpoint in the catch.

Comment: The exceptions are catched. But I cant reproduce them. This is the exception : The specified Visual is not an ancestor of this Visual.

Comment: Well thats a pretty specific message... you can check the ancestor hierarchy of your `XamDialogWindow Window` when the exception occurs and if the `MainWindow` is not an ancestor, focus on the questions *why isn't it?* and *what is the actual ancestor?*

Comment: The problem is: how to reproduce it? Can I reproduce it in a simple app?

Comment: Just create two windows that both use the same adorner or generally, create another window before the one with the adorner so that `Application.Current.MainWindow` doesn't point to the window that contains the adorner.

Comment: In the visual tree log I see that the MainWindow is the ancestor

Comment: That could be a race condition, like if the visual hierarchy changes just before GetLayoutClip is called. If you add a Try/Catch, does your app still works as expected? If yes, that would be a hint of such an issue. It could also be a bug, you could contact infragistics, for example : https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/96558.aspx

Comment: @SimonMourier I have a screenshot from the moment the exception occurs  this screenshot show the dialog in the top left corner and the adorner is already correctly drawn (with a white rectangle in the center) , it looks like the dialog isn't yet positioned when the exception occurs. I contacted Infragistics about it.

Comment: @SimonMourier any ideas?

Comment: not more than 5 hours ago

Comment: @SimonMourier maybe you recognize the behavior I described

Answer (score 0):

Your window is not present in the Visual Tree. You have two options:

1. Listen for the **Loaded** event. Then, when loaded, start listening for the other events (Moved, WindowStateChanged, SizeChanged).
2. Use dispatcher where necessary and then hope for the best.

As for your request for a sample app I can assure you that the issue you are seeing is *unbelievably* hard to reproduce.

Comment: I contacted Infragistics about it, they experienced the same in one of their controls, their fix was to try/catch the exception which fixed it for them.